# Algorithm for removing fewest edges to force increase in length of shortest path in unweighted undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Given an adjacency matrix for an unweighted undirected graph, is there an efficient way (polynomial algorithm) to expand/increase the length of shortest path between any given two nodes s and t?

**Example:**

In the example below, there are 5 different 'shortest paths' from vertex s=1 to vertex t=5, each having length 3.  I want to remove the fewest number of edges so that the shortest path length is forced to become 4 or more. (Disconnecting the graph is ok.)

Adjacency matrix (extended to correct the example):

```
 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 
 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  
 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

representing this graph:

[image: Modified graph (AKE)]

Minimum cost for forcing the shortest path length to increase from 3 to 4 is the removal of two edges (1,2) and (5,9)

**Goal:**

Can you give any ideas for a general algorithm that finds the set of edges that must be removed in a general case?

---

**Correction:** As noted in my comments, this example is not complete.  By adding two more vertices 10 and 11 (shown in red), the example is rescued.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the adjacency matrix for the example you describe (saves us from having to think of one).

Comment: Which vertices are s and t?

Comment: @ake 1 is the source and 5 is the sink

Comment: Then if you remove (1,2) and (5,9) you disconnect the graph.  So there is then NO path between 1 and 5, so how do you get a path of length 4?

Comment: @AKE I mentioned in the question. the main goal is increasing the length of shortest path by removing min # of edges. (the connectivity of graph isn't matter)

Comment: in other say, if the shortest path between s and t is 5, we must remove min # of edges so that there isn't any path with length 5 between s and t anymore.

Comment: I understand the question.  However, your example and your claims about it are incorrect.  I'm suggesting that you put up a good working example.  It shows that you've made some effort yourself.

Comment: I've fixed your example for you -- note the extra nodes in red -- also the adjacency table.  Now, what have you tried on this working example?

Comment: @AKE: I solved the question by max-flow min-cut theorem. the answer is the edges of a min-cut

Comment: Well done.  Why not post your own answer?  Also: it cannot be the entire min cut, as otherwise the graph is disconnected and there is no path between source and sink.  Presumably you mean a subset of the cut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with an approach I mentioned in third comment of "Pål GD" answer. Here's the java code of that. Hope you find it helpful!

```
// BFS to find the depth of every node (from source node)
// graph is the adjacency matrix.
// elements of row zero and column zero are all useless. this program
// works with indices >=1 
private int[][] BFS (int[][] graph, int source, boolean SPedges){
    int[][] temp = null;

    // nodes is number of graph nodes. (nodes == graph.length - 1)
    if (SPedges){
        temp = new int[nodes + 1][nodes + 1];
    }
    else{
        depth[source] = 0;
    }
    LinkedList<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Q.clear();
    visited[source] = true;
    Q.addFirst(source);
    while (!Q.isEmpty()){
        int u = Q.removeLast();
        for (int k = 1; k <= nodes; k++){
            if (!SPedges){
                // checking if there's a edge between node u and other nodes
                if (graph[u][k] == 1 && visited[k] == false){
                    visited[k] = true;
                    depth[k] = depth[u] + 1;
                    Q.addFirst(k);
                }
            }
            else{
                if (graph[u][k] == 1 && depth[k] == depth[u] - 1){
                    Q.addFirst(k);
                    temp[k][u] = 1;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    return temp;
}

// fills the edges of shortest path graph in flow 
private ArrayList<Edge> maxFlow(int[][] spg, int source, int sink){ 
    int u = source;
    ArrayList<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer> (depth[sink]);
    path.add(source);
    Arrays.fill(visited, false);
    visited[source] = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= nodes + 1; i++){
        if (i == nodes + 1){
            if (u == source)
                break;
            u = path.get(path.size() - 2);
            i = path.remove(path.size() - 1);
        }
        else if(spg[u][i] == 1 && visited[i] == false){
            visited[i] = true;
            path.add(i);
            if (i == sink){
                for(int k = 0; k < path.size() - 1; k++){
                    spg[path.get(k)][path.get(k+1)] = 0;
                    spg[path.get(k+1)][path.get(k)] = 1;
                }
                i = 0;
                u = source;
                path.clear();
                path.add(u);
                Arrays.fill(visited, false);
            }
            else{
                u = i;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    LinkedList<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Q.clear();

    Arrays.fill(visited, false);

    visited[source] = true;
    Q.addFirst(source);
    while (!Q.isEmpty()){
        u = Q.removeLast();
        for (int k = 1; k <= nodes; k++){
            if (spg[u][k] == 1 && visited[k] == false){
                visited[k] = true;
                Q.addFirst(k);
            }   
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= nodes; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j <= nodes; j++){
            if ((spg[i][j] == 1) && (visited[i] ^ visited[j])){
                edges.add(new Edge(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    return edges;
}

public void Solv(){
    // adjacency matrix as g. represents the graph.
    // first we find depth of each node corresponding to source node by a BFS from source
    BFS(g, s, false);

    // shortest path length from source to sink (node t)
    SPL = depth[t];

    // shortest path graph
    // it's a subgraph of main graph consisting only edges that are in a shortest path
    // between s and t
    spg = BFS(g, t, true);

    // lastly we find edges of a min cut in shortest paths graph
    // and store them in "edges"
    edges = maxFlow(spg, s, t);
}    

class Edge{
    private int begin, end;
    public Edge(int begin, int end){
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new String(String.valueOf(begin) + " " + String.valueOf(end));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Input:  G = (V,E), vertices s, t and positive integer d.

Question:  Minimize the number of edges needed to delete such that dist(s,t) >= d.

This problem is NP-hard for d > 3 and polynomially solvable for other values of d.

The problem is FPT parameterized on the distance d and number of edges you are allowed to delete, k:  The algorithm is as follows:  Find an (s,t)-path of length at most d and branch on the d edges to which you can delete.  This results in an algorithm which runs in time O(d^k * n^2).

It's para-NP-complete (resp. W[1]-hard) when parameterized by just d (resp. just k).

Ref: Paths of bounded length and their cuts: Parameterized complexity and algorithms, Golovach, P.A. and Thilikos, D.M., Discrete Optimization volume 8, number 1, pages 72 - 86, year 2011, publisher Elsevier.

Comment: Can you please give a reference to your source on this?

Comment: this is p question! I solved it by finding max flow for given graph and then finding min-cut edges by BFS. I'll post my answer soon.

Comment: @templatetypedef Added reference, they refer to the problem as BEUC, Bounded Edge Undirected (s,t)-cut.

Comment: @alireza The problem is polynomially solvable if and only if both the distance and number of edges you are allowed to delete are considered to be constant (given that P != NP).